# How can I find out about notification delivery (ti.goosh)

Tags: push-notification, titanium, push, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I use Appcelerator Titanium and I have module ti.goosh for push notification. How can I find out about notification delivery? In 'callback' I can find out about opening the notification, but I want to also know that the notification is in the device tray (for example using console.log).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends on what kind of message you are sending. A FCM data message is handled by the module with the `NotificationCompat.Builder` but if you are sending a normal FCM notification message the system is creating the notification and displaying it. You will only know if the notification was clicked by the user (like you already do) or if it arrived while the app was in foreground.